# Wouldn’t Farquaad already be a King?

Tags: shrek

In [*Shrek The Musical*](https://shrekthemusical.co.uk/), it’s revealed he was the son of the Princess from *The Princess and the Pea*.

> “My momma was a princess, who left her crown behind.”

So if that’s true, why does he have to marry a princess to become a king? Shouldn’t he be a king already? Or is it because she “left her crown behind”?

Comment: The son of a Princess isn't (necessarily) a King. For instance, Prince Edward's children are a Lady and a Viscount; https://metro.co.uk/2018/05/19/prince-edward-childrens-names-not-duke-7551633/

Comment: Is the musical canon with regard to the movies?

Comment: @BruceWayne - You mean aside from everyone singing and Fiona dancing around with her younger selves at the end?

Answer (score 23):

The next lines are fairly telling;

> My momma was a princess
>   Who left her crown behind.
>   **Daddy was her true love, so
>
>   Momma didn't mind**.
>
> I never knew my momma
>   But **she could've been a queen
>
>   She married way beneath her...**
>   Beneath her knee, I mean.

It would appear that she was disinherited for marrying a commoner. She could have become the queen through inheritance (or possibly married a king?) but either way her title was withdrawn and she was left married to a nobody with a child (Farquaad) who was also a commoner.

Comment: It could also mean that, as a princess, she could have married a king, and thus become a queen.

Comment: @Acccumulation - That seems a possibility, especially given that a Lord can become a King by marrying a Princess.

Comment: +1. Perhaps relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morganatic_marriage.

Comment: @ruakh Also potentially relevant: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Household_Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Household_Law) / [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayako_Kuroda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayako_Kuroda)

Comment: I always thought that "married way beneath her" line was a joke about how short Farquaad was.

Comment: @puppetsock - That's the joke. She married a commoner (beneath her [station](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/station)) who's short (literally beneath her).

Comment: @Valorum Ok, I came here to have a good time and I'm honestly feeling so attacked right now.

Comment: @LordFarquaad - Is it because you've got a short temper?

Comment: My wife participated in the musical recently. Specifically, Lord Farquaad's father in the musical is a fairytale creature, Grumpy of the seven dwarves in *Snow White*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Are dwarves "fairytale creatures" though?

Comment: @Valorum: In *Shrek: the Musical*, they are. It probably is worth noting that they're "dwarves" rather than "dwarfs", which is an important distinction.