# What kingdom was Farquaad’s mother Princess of?

Tags: shrek

In *Shrek the Musical* Farquaad says:

> My momma was a princess
>
> Who left her crown behind.

The Shrek wikia says she was Princess of Duloc, but the Mirror only said “You can be king by marrying a princess,” to Farquaad, so does that really apply to the Princess’s parents i.e. Farquaad’s maternal grandparents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wouldn’t Farquaad already be a King?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190176/wouldn-t-farquaad-already-be-a-king)

Comment: @Valorum That older Q&A doesn't seem to have anything to do with which kingdom his mother was a princess of.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Indeed, but there are two questions here and one of them is a dupe.

Comment: @Valorum If you agree that the older question has nothing to do with what this one is asking, then how is one of them a dupe?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The older question addresses the point of whether Farquaad's parentage would deliver him the throne. I agree that the question of what she's the queen of is on-topic but I'm reluctant to edit this question sufficiently to remove the elements that are dupey.

Comment: @Valorum The fact that you're reluctant to edit it doesn't make it a dupe though.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm reluctant to edit it because it would change the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

from [Shrekwiki](http://shrek.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Farquaad):

> In Shrek The Musical, Farquaad's past is revealed during the musical number "The Ballad of Farquaad". **Farquaad's mother was revealed to be a Princess named Pea from the Princess and the Pea** and his father being Grumpy (which explains his comically short stature) from Snow White. **They married for love, and his mother was apparently disinherited from her crown.**

As for the fairy tale, it's a short story and doesn't mention names (characters or kingdoms): 
[The Princess and the pea](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/PriPea.shtml)

Comment: This addresses *who* his mother was, but not what she was princess of.

Comment: the fairy tale doesn't mention her name  or any kingdom's name I'm afraid...